# Angular JS $http promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

i just want to ask about $http and promise usage, i seem to have a problem understanding on how to use it properly, i have ready some threads and guides on how to implement, i may have misunderstood it but here is what i did. I keep it as simple as possible in order for me to grasp it.

```
this.getAll = function(){
    var details = [];

    var deffered = $q.defer();

    var promise = $http.get('../test_data/patient_list.json');

    promise.then(function(response){
        $log.debug(response.data);
        angular.copy(response.data, details);
        details = response.data
    });

    return details;
};
```

during `promise.then()` data do exists, but when i try to copy it to another array after `promise.then` call `details` is empty. How come? Im a bit confused now, can anyone point or teach me how to properly handle data on `$http`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.getAll = function(){
var details = [];

var deffered = $q.defer();

var promise = $http.get('../test_data/patient_list.json');

return promise.then(function(response){
    $log.debug(response.data);
    angular.copy(response.data, details);
    details = response.data
    return details; 
});

};
```

you have to return the promise then return details inside the `.then()` block.

you can also do the following:

```
this.getAll = function(){
 return $http.get('../test_data/patient_list.json')
  .then(function (response) {
     return response.data
  });
}
```

Comment: ohh but where does "deffered" come in this picture?

Comment: @lemoncodes deferred is another way to handle promiese especially when you whan to wrap a callback or non-promise function call into a promise.  By default, $http.get() returns a promise, so we don;t need $q.defer()

Comment: yes i tried the code above, but when i return the "details" it returned the promise, i expected the actual data to be returned?, i think i misunderstood the returning part of the code..

Comment: @lemoncodes http request is an async call, so if you want the data to be available in hour controller for instance, call `getAll()` in your state definition resolve block (if you are using ui-roter or angular default router).  The thing is response.data is only guaranteed to be defined and available inside the `.then()` block

Comment: hmm it is just under a service i created, i wanted to have it resolve and return only an array, basically the service will do all the ajax call and just return the data i need. so i need to parse the promise before i return it to the controller where the service function "getAll" is being invoked.

Comment: That is not the ideal way, call service.getAll() in the resolve block of the router that is linked to the controller. This way it is injected automatically to the controller. example: https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/

Comment: ohhh i see, gotcha there.. thanks